# Need to find the count of customers that have an order with 20 different products in it

Tags: mysql, sql

[Database Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14ZkL.png)

Having trouble figuring out how to find the number of customers in the database that have an order with a certain number of products in it. I just need to return the total number of customers that meet this criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT curtomer_id) OVER ()
FROM customers
JOIN orders
JOIN products
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) > 20
```

or maybe (if window function cannot be used in this context)

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT DISTINCT curtomer_id
              FROM customers
              JOIN orders
              JOIN products
              GROUP BY order_id
              HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) > 20 )
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the customers that meet the criteria using:

```
select customerNumber, count(distinct od.productcode) as num_products
from orders o join
     orderdetails od
     on o.ordernumber = od.ordernumber
group by o.ordernumber, o.customernumber
having count(distinct od.productcode) >= 20;
```

You can then use a subquery to count the customers:

```
select count(distinct customerNumber)
from (select customerNumber, count(distinct od.productcode) as num_products
      from orders o join
           orderdetails od
           on o.ordernumber = od.ordernumber
      group by o.ordernumber, o.customernumber
      having count(distinct od.productcode) >= 20
     ) co;
```